# Error Loading PHP Page On 4G

Tags: php, wifi, 4g

I have a new webpage that runs perfectly on any device when connected to wifi, but when the device is running on 4G or anything else but Wifi the page does not load and this error is displayed...

```
Technical Description:
502 bad gateway - response error, a bad response was received from another proxy 
server or the destination orgin server
```

The page is just a simple php login page, every thing is connected to the database too. What could be causing this to not load? The page is...

`http://kissbeta.comule.com/Beta/LoginRegister/demo.php`

Thank you for your time and I appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: It's your data connection.  Works properly on both iPhone and desktop for me.

Comment: Thank you for testing that, but all of my friends are having this same issue with the site.

Answer (score 0):

This is a network error.You will have to contact your ISP regarding this.Maybe the hostname has been blocked.

Usually different kinds of network are served by independent network setups.Hence a rule that applies to 4g might affect only 4g and not other networks.

For instance In India,the site pastebin.com is not available from WiMax of our ISP but it is available from the wired lan of the same ISP.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but other users are having this same problem, so is their a solution to fix it for everyone trying to access it via 4G?

Comment: your error specifically says it is a gateway error.A gateway is a computer system(network enttity) maintained by the ISP.There is nothing you can do about it(unless you maintain a local gateway)

Comment: ALright thank you for clearing that up, I appreciate your help.